# C# how to get mac address with colon

Tags: c#, networking

the code :

```
var macAddr =
      (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
       where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
       select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

the output :

> 0800275283A8

how covert to :

> 08:00:27:52:83:A8

Comment: no , that not solve my problem

Comment: how did it not solve your problem?

Comment: 'nic' does not exist in the current context

Comment: see my answer, I've shown how to implement the solution proposed there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var macAddr =
              (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
               where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
               select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes()).FirstOrDefault();

 string formattedMacAddr = string.Join (":", (from z in macAddr select z.ToString ("X2")).ToArray());
 Console.WriteLine(formattedMacAddr);

//outputs this format: 08:00:27:52:83:A8
```